# print hashtable session variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, perl

Does anyone know how to access a hashtable session variable from javascript?  I can create one in perl and print it out like this:

```
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
$session->param("controllerHash", \%controllerHash);
my $hash_ref = $session->param('controllerHash');
print Dumper $hash_ref;
```

But I can't figure out how to access it from javascript.
I tried something like this:

```
function billingViewControllerChanged() {
      var controllerHash = Session['controllerHash'];
      for (var k in controllerHash) {
              console.log('key: '+k +', value: ' +controllerHash[k]);
      }
}
```

But I see this in the firefox Console:

```
ReferenceError: Session is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to serialize your Perl data structure with JSON, which JavaScript can parse natively.

```
use JSON;
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, undef, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
$session->param("controllerHash", \%controllerHash);
my $hash_ref = $session->param('controllerHash');
my $controllerHashJSON = JSON->new->encode( $hash_ref );


print <<"__EOF__";    # in CGI, STDOUT is output to the client
function billingViewControllerChanged() {
      var controllerHash = $controllerHashJSON;
      for (var k in controllerHash) {
              console.log('key: '+k +', value: ' +controllerHash[k]);
      }
}
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea mob.  Unfortunately, I can't get JSON to work even though it appears to be installed.  "Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC".  When I do yum install 'perl(JSON)' I get message "Package perl-neto-io-JSON-2.53-1.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do"

Comment: Got it working in the terminal window at least by doing "export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/neto_io/lib/perl5/".  Thanks mob!

Comment: Got it working in the browser by doing "sudo yum install perl-JSON"

Answer (score 0):

You can't get there from here.

Server side code runs on the server, javascript runs in the browser.

If you need to access server side session data you'll need to either include it in a  block on your web page, or provide a URL with a CGI script that returns it in a form that the javascript can use.

Comment: The web page queries an oracle database for records that match two filter values selected from comboboxes.  When one of the combobox values change, I need to change the values of the second.  All the combinations add up to 32000 lines.  I don't want to pull that amount of data from the server for every filter change.  I want it stored somewhere on the browser.  Isn't a session value the place to store it?  What is "a block on your web page"?